# New post now showing up in Like Box

Tags: stream, facebook-like

I have seen where other people have posted about this. I have a like box on a client's site and the new posts are showing up on their timeline under "Older Posts" even though they were just published hours ago - which makes them not show up in the Like Box. Is there a setting on their FB page that could be causing this. I have the Like Box settings correct (show_faces=true&border_color=%23555555&stream=true&header=false&appId=180146438719420;force_wall=true&") and even added that last part (force_wall) after somebody suggested it. Still nothing.

Anyone figure this out yet? Thanks!